# Subspace of R^3 Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ of dimension $k$, then there is a unique subspace $R$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ of dimension $3 - k$ such that every vector in $S$ is orthogonal to every vector in $R$.

I'm having a little getting started with this proof. I know that vectors are orthogonal if their dot product is 0. But how do I show that all the combinations of vectors in $S$ and $R$ produce this result?

Comment: Take $R = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : \langle x,v\rangle = 0 \quad\forall v\in S\}$

Comment: Take the orthogonal complement of $S$, and use the projection theorem to prove that the dimension of the orthogonal complement of $S$ is $3-k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Geometric explanation

$k=0 \to R=\mathbb{R}^3 $.

$k=1$,then $R$ is the plane which is orthogonal to the line $S$.

$k=2$,then $R$ is the line which is orthogonal to the plane $S$.

$k=3$,then $R$ is $\{0\}$.

## Before proof

I'll prove a general proposition for you and you can get your conclusion immediately from it:

$V$ is an inner-product space.$S$ is its subspace.$R$ is the set consisting of all the vectors which are othogonal to every vector in $S$.Then $R$ is a subsapce of $V$ and $V=S \oplus R$.

## Algebraic proof

Suppose $r_1,r_2 \in R,s \in S$.

We have

$$(k_1r_1+k_2r_2,s)=k_1(r_1,s)+k_2(r_2,s)=0+0=0$$.

So $k_1r_1+k_2r_2 \in R$,saying $R$ is a subspace.

All we need to prove now ,is that

$$V=S \oplus R.$$

Supposing $\alpha \in S \cap R$,we get $(\alpha,\alpha)=0$,so $\alpha=0$.

That is to say,$S \cap R=\{0\}$,so $S+R$ is a direct sum.

Pick an orthonormal basis of $S$:$\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_k$ and extend it to a basis of $V:\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_k,\beta_{k+1},\ldots,\beta{n}$.

Running Schmidt orthogonalization on this basis.For $\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_k$ is already orthonormal,we get the orthonormal basis of $V$:

$$\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_k,\varepsilon_{k+1},\ldots,\varepsilon_n$$
.

$\varepsilon_{k+1},\ldots,\varepsilon_n$ are in $R$ for they are orthogonal to $\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_k$.So we get:

$$V=L(\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_k)+L(\varepsilon_{k+1},\ldots,\varepsilon_n) \subset S+R \subset V$$.

Say $V=S+R$.

**QED.**